# xll sdk: When we get xltypeRef instead of xltypeSref. Trying to get xltypeRef as it provides sheet id

Tags: xll

Trying to get xltypeRef as it returns sheet id. When I call the udf function from VBA it returns xltypeRef and I get the sheet Id but deploying involves registry entries which I want to avoid. I get xltypeSref when I call the same udf function from Excel which does not give sheet id.  Is there any way to get xltypeRef instead of xltypeSref when I call udf directly from Excel?

Comment: Can you provide more details because it is not clear, especially regarding registries entries ? where do you need the sheet id , in the C code or in Excel ?

Comment: If I call the udf function from VBA I am getting xltypeRef through xloper object received in C dll  and if I directly call udf function from Excel, it give me xltypeSref through xloper object received in c dll. In order to call it from VBA, I need to add function to VBA module which in turn calls my udf. I will have to deploy VBA module as .xla file which needs registry entries to deploy it in excel. Hence I want a solution which returns xltypeRef(which provides idsheet) instead of xltypeSref through xloper object when user enters the udf function on Excel.

Comment: Did you try to make an additional call to  xlfCaller to get the sheet Id ? see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687912.aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687847%28v=office.15%29.aspx